# WCF service in silverlight not saving file to server

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, silverlight

Still new to silverlight and WCF setup so was doing some experimenting when I ran into trouble.

SETUP:

My solution has a website, a WCF service and a silver-light application. For now just consider the silver-light project to be a button. I have successfully added a service reference to the WCF service in the silver-light project.

In one of the methods expose in the service, I create a system.io.stream-writer object, write a test line to it and then close it.

I call this method in the silver-light app and when it is completed i turn a rectangle yellow to make sure that the a sync method has completed.

The solution builds without error and when I run the website with the silver-light app and press the button, the rectangle turns yellow (meaning that the event has completed) but the text file has nothing written in it.

So I looked at any error messages in the completed event handler and surely got this error message:

"An error occurred while trying to make a request to URI '`http://localhost:20436/TransmitData.svc`'. This could be due to attempting to access a service in a cross-domain way without a proper cross-domain policy in place, or a policy that is unsuitable for SOAP services. You may need to contact the owner of the service to publish a cross-domain policy file and to ensure it allows SOAP-related HTTP headers to be sent. This error may also be caused by using internal types in a web service proxy without using the InternalsVisibleToAttribute attribute. Please see the inner exception for more details"

Since I am new to silverlight and WCF, I need some pointers for debugging this.

Well I tried fiddler as well and this is the message I am getting:

"a:InternalServiceFaultObject reference not set to an instance of an object.Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at WCF.TransmitData.transmitRecord(AttendanceRecord user) in C:\Users\waqasjafri\Desktop\AttendanceSystem\TransmitData\TransmitData.svc.cs:line 32 at SyncInvoketransmitRecord(Object , Object[] , Object[] ) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage41(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)System.NullReferenceException"

Thanks

Comment: To debug service issues use Attach To Process and attach your debugger to the IIS App Pool (w3wp.exe process) that your service is running under.  You should be able to put break points in your service methods and get more info.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to configure your service to be [callable across domain boundaries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197955(v=vs.95).aspx) with a `clientaccesspolicy.xml` or `crossdomain.xml` file.

Also take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3156132/wcf-and-silverlight-crossdomain-xml) for more details.

Comment: I investigated a little more and found a few more details that i edited into my question. Could you look at it again? maybe that will tell you more about the problem.